# Algorithm to generate a 'nearly sorted' or 'k sorted' list?

Tags: algorithm

I want to generate some test data to test a function that merges 'k sorted' lists (lists where each element is at most k positions away from it's correct sorted position) into a single fully sorted list. I have an approach that works but I'm not sure how well randomized it is and I feel there should be a simpler / more elegant way to do this. My current approach:

1. Generate n random elements paired with an integer index.
2. Sort random elements.
3. Set paired index for each element to its sorted position.
4. Work backwards through the elements, swapping each element with an element a random distance between 1 and k positions behind it in the list. Only swap with the target element if its paired index is its current index (this avoids swapping an element that is already out of place and moving it further than k positions away from where it should be).
5. Copy the perturbed elements out into another list.

Like I say, this works but I'm interested in alternative / better approaches.

Comment: And do you require the output to be fully sorted (0-sorted), or merely k-sorted?

Comment: The output is intended to be k-sorted (for use as test input to an algorithm that merges k-sorted lists).

Comment: I just realized I got my inputs and outputs mixed up.  You will create a number of lists, each of which is k-sorted.  The algorithm you are testing will merged those lists into one list.  That (single, large) merged list will be 0-sorted or k-sorted?

Comment: The algorithm I want to test is intended to produce a fully sorted list but that shouldn't be important for the purposes of this question. I just want to generate appropriate k-sorted test inputs for it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could just fill an array with random integers and then run quicksort on it with a custom stopping condition.

If in a particular quicksort recursion your `start` and `end` indexes are less than `k` apart, then just return instead of continuing to recur.

Because of how quicksort works, every number in the `start..end` interval belongs somewhere in that region; worst case is that `array[start]` might really belong at `array[end]` (or vice versa) in truly sorted order. So, assuring that `start` and `end` are no more than `k` apart should be sufficient.

Comment: But this means that values in the middle of the range will be less than `k` apart... I don't think this will be very uniform.

Answer (score 1):

You can generate array of random numbers and then h-sort it like in [shellsort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort), but without fiew last sorting steps when **h** is less then **k**.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Randomly permute disjoint segments of length k. (Eg. 1 to K, k+1 to 2k ...)

Step 2: Permute conditionally again by swapping (that they don't break k-sorted assumption (1+t yo k+t, k+1+t to 1+2k+t ...) where t  is a number between 1 and k (most preferably k/2)

Probably repeat step 2 multiple times with different t.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem, you want an algorithm to randomly pick a single `k`-sorted list of length `n`, uniformly selected from the universe `U` of all `k`-sorted lists of length `n`.  (You will then run this algorithm `m` times to produce `m` lists as input test data.)

The first step is to count them.  What is the size of `U`? `|U|`

The next step is to enumerate them.  Create any one-to-one mapping `F` between the integers `(1,2,...,|U|)` and `k`-sorted lists of length `n`.

Then randomly select an integer `x` between 1 and `|U|` inclusive, and then apply `F(x)` to get the list.

Comment: This is just describing what uniform selection on a finite set is, it doesn't lead to a useful algorithm.