# python quicksort with custom stopping condition

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, quicksort

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19826351/3080893) answer, I want to employ quicksort with custom stopping conditions in order to produce a k-sorted array from an unsorted array in Python. I take for ganted that `len(array) = m*k` so there will be `m` sub-arrays (not necessarily sorted) and elements of subarray `i` are lower or equal than elements of subarray `j` with `i<j`.

```
def partition(array, left, right):
    pivot = array[right]
    i = left - 1

    for j in range(left, right):
        if array[j] <= pivot:
            i += 1
            temp = array[i]
            array[i] = array[j]
            array[j] = temp
    temp = array[right]
    array[right] = array[i + 1]
    array[i + 1] = temp
    return i + 1

def k_quicksort(array, left, right, k):
    if right - left > k:
        p = partition(array, left, right)
        k_quicksort(array, p + 1, right, k)
        k_quicksort(array, left, p - 1, k)
```

The answer i'm refering to in the link suggests that i should change the stopping condition and check if the start (`left`) and end (`right`) indexes are more than k apart, if not then do not reccur. I test this algorithm with

```
x = [scipy.random.randint(1,100) for i in range(16)]
k_quicksort(x,0,len(x)-1,4)
```

And i get

```
x = [19, 13, 1, 28, 42, 49, 73, 59, 62, 56, 74, 89, 78, 90, 91, 98]
```

Which is awfuly wrong. Have i not understood well the customary stopping condition or is it some other buggy bug?? Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: you can't assume anything on the values of `left` and `right`. What you can do however, is skip sorting right if `p > k`

Comment: I don't understand your hint. Compared to the length of the list, `k` will be relatively small. Most of the times `p` will be bigger than `k`.

Comment: Yes, but you still have to do the partition, because you have no idea where the values are in the original array. Without any prior knowledge of what the array is like, the value of `p` after the partition is uniformly distributed.

Comment: basically, you always need to do the partition, and you need to recurse as long as `p <= k`, because after `k_quicksort` completes for a given range, that range is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

To limit to `k-sorted` array, you need to skip the recursion for the end of the array:

```
def swap(arr, i, j):
    arr[i], arr[j] = arr[j], arr[i]

def partition(array, left, right):
    pivot = array[right - 1]
    i = left

    for j in range(left, right - 1):
        if array[j] <= pivot:
            swap(array, i, j)
            i += 1
    swap(array, right - 1, i)
    return i

def k_quicksort(array, left, right, k):
    if left == right:
        return
    p = partition(array, left, right)
    k_quicksort(array, left, p, k)
    if k > p + 1:
        k_quicksort(array, p + 1, right, k)
```

You need the partition to ensure that what you are sorting are the right values. But you can skip the recursion (and therefore the sort) for all the values right of `k`.

Edit: fixed your quicksort.

Comment: This code as it is (copy-pasted) gives maximum recursion depth error. Is the usage of `k_quicksort` as before (`k_quicksort(x,0,len(x)-1,k)`)? My head will explode (no offense)

Comment: no, that's `k_quicksort(x,0,len(x),k)` (left bound included, right bound excluded)

Comment: I'm sorry but this still produces the same error. Also my quicksort was wrong due to copy-paste error (the last swap of partition was inside of for loop instead of outside.

Comment: @Sorrop a couple of boundary verification issues. I haven't written a QS in a long time... all fixed now.

Comment: Runtime error fixed but i'm afraid this does not solve the problem of k-sorting. I tried input `x=[48, 12, 63, 46, 69, 39, 60, 54, 6, 79, 26, 64, 68, 15, 83, 29]` and got `[6, 12, 15, 26, 29, 39, 60, 54, 48, 79, 63, 64, 68, 46, 83, 69]` which is wrong. Maybe you are confusing this with finding k-smallest elements?

Comment: @Sorrop it would seem that I am, yes.